# How to insert a space in a charArray in an exact position [Java]

Tags: java, arrays, char

My problem is that I'm getting a `String` and I need to check if there is a space in the 4th position but starting from the end. If in this position there is not a space, I should insert it.

For example:
I get this String: TW12EF, need to get it like this: TW1 2EF

First of all I get the 4 last characters in a char `array` because I also need to check if they are numbers or letters.

With this method I check if there is a space:

```
public static boolean isSpace(){
    return String.valueOf(charArray[0]).matches("[ \\t\\n\\x0B\\f\\r]");
}
```

`charArray` contains the last 4 characters of the input `String`

If `charArray[0]` wouldn't be a space, I want to insert a space in the 2nd place (`charArray[1]`)

If there is something that I can correct in the question to make it easier to understand, just let me know and I will try to make it better for next questions.

Comment: Do you always have 0 or 1 space? Will the space always be in that place (if it is present)?

Comment: You can use `substring` for adding a space, like this:

`String string = "TW12EF";
    // Your check
    String newString = string.substring(0, string.length() - 3) + " " + string.substring(string.length() - 3, string.length());`

Comment: Yes it should be only one of this options: 1 space or 0 space. In case that the user introduce more spaces, then it is wrong. Then I will let the user know that he should introduce a right code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple and direct solution (most likely faster than using a regular expression) is to get the 4th to the last character (if it exists), and if it isn't a white-space, insert a space at that position.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "TW12EF";

    int insertPos = str.length() - 4;
    if (insertPos >= 0) {
        char ch = str.charAt(insertPos);
        if (!Character.isWhitespace(ch)) {
            str = new StringBuilder(str).insert(insertPos + 1, ' ').toString();
        }
    }

    System.out.println(str);
}
```

A whitespace is determined by invoking [`isWhitespace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace-char-), which returns true for space but also tabs or line feeds, like you did in your question. The character is inserted by leveraging the [`StringBuilder#insert`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#insert-int-char-) method, which is more direct that taking 2 substrings and concatenating them.

Comment: That work pretty good, but I also need to check what are the last three charachters and I am still inserting the last three in a charArray.
Is that a good way for checking it, or is it too slow?
Thanks a lot for the answer, it helped me a lot.

Comment: @MarioJ.G. If you want to check the last 3 characters, you can just add 3 calls to `charAt` and verify each time the character returned. This would be pretty direct and fast.

Answer (score 5):

A quick, *dirty* regex will help :

```
String p = "TW12EF";
System.out.println(p.replaceAll("(.)\\s*(\\S.{2})$", "$1 $2")); // Select a character followed by 0 or more spaces and followed by 3 non-space characters. And replace multiple spaces if they exist with a single space
```

O/P :

```
TW1 2EF
```

Also works if there are one or more spaces after the 3rd char (from the left)

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But what do you exactly mean with "dirty"? 
That it will work only for the case that I get a code like that = "TW12EF"?
I will try to read good regex in API to understand it, at the moment is pretty confusing for me

Comment: @MarioJ.G. - By *dirty*, I meant that its difficult to read and maintain. And slow as well

Comment: Ok, now it make sense with "dirty", thanks a lot anyway for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

As char is a primitive data type, the comparison can be done simply with

```
if (charArray[0] == ' ') {
    char[] temp = new char[5];
    temp[0] = ' ';
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        temp[i] = charArray[i - 1];
    }
    charArray = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "TW12EF";

        processStr(str);
    }

    public static final int SPACE_POS = 4, OFFSET = 1;
    public static String processStr(String str)
    {

        if(!Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(str.length() - SPACE_POS)))
        {
            str = String.format("%s %s", str.substring(0, str.length() - SPACE_POS + OFFSET), str.substring(SPACE_POS - OFFSET));
        }

        return str;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this？

```
`   String s="TW12EF";
    String result="";
    int length=s.length();
    for(int i=length-1;i>-1;i--){
        if(i==length-4&&s.charAt(i)!=' '){
            result+=" ";
        }
        result+=s.charAt(length-i-1);
    }
    System.out.println(result);`
```